# setObject() method of PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

Can I use the `setObject()` method of `PreparedStatement` for all datatypes (like `String`, `int` or `double`)?

What are the potential problems if I use that?

```
protected void fillStatement(PreparedStatement stmt, Object[] params)
        throws SQLException {

        if (params == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            if (params[i] != null) {
                stmt.setObject(i + 1, params[i]);
            } else {
                stmt.setNull(i + 1, Types.OTHER);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can, and it should work, and I suspect this is what libraries like Hibernate do too. As usual, some drivers may be just a little bit buggy in some corner-cases.

Comment: For example, Oracle seems to have trouble with setNull: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbutils/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/dbutils/AbstractQueryRunner.java?revision=1362322&view=markup#l215

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421374/arithmetic-overflow-or-other-arithmetic-exception-when-using-setobject-method Refer this link for more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use `setObject()` exclusively with MySQL and I've never had a problem with it. I cannot speak for other databases or other vendors.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially have an issue with Blobs or specialized date fields like MSSQL DateTimeOffeet.

Also I found an issue "Unable to convert between java.lang.Character and JAVA_OBJECT."

If the parameter is a single character type.

```
    if (param instanceof Character) {
        param = "" + param;
    }
```