# Arithmetic overflow or other arithmetic exception when using setObject method

Tags: java, sql

Following is the query which I'm trying to handle in Prepared statement. In which AmountOnHand & ReorderPointAmt is of data type Decimal.

```
Query 1: SELECT AmountOnHand FROM TableA WHERE AmountOnHand <= (ReorderPointAmt*56.0/100);
```

Where 56.0 is a dynamic value.

So I updated the query as below

```
Query 2: SELECT AmountOnHand FROM TableA WHERE AmountOnHand <= (ReorderPointAmt*?);
```

But when this query is executed I'm getting the following exception:

```
Arithmetic overflow or other arithmetic exception occurred.. SQLCODE=-802, SQLSTATE=22003, DRIVER=4.15.82.
```

I'm able to fix this issue by updating the query like below

```
 Query 3: SELECT AmountOnHand FROM TableA WHERE AmountOnHand <= (ReorderPointAmt * CAST(? AS DECIMAL));
```

But I could not understand what made the Query:2 to end up in exception. I'm using `java.sql.PreparedStatement.setObject(index, Object)` to feed the value for Query:2.

I tried by setting `Double` & `Float` Object in `setObject` method. Still facing the issue.

Comment: Can you try using `java.sql.PreparedStatement.setDouble`

Comment: The problem is java.sql.PreparedStatement.setObject(..) comes with the framework. I'm not suppose to edit that.

Comment: Are you sure the `ReorderPointAmt` is `Decimal`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes it is of DECIMAL(30, 15)

Answer (score 0):

use any appropriate datatype like `java.sql.PreparedStatement.setString(index, "String value")` or 
`setInt()` or `setDouble()`

Comment: The problem is java.sql.PreparedStatement.setObject(..) comes with the framework. I'm not suppose to edit that.