# Using setObject() instead of all data types in ojdbc

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, ojdbc

can I use `setObject()` method of `PreparedStatement` for all datatypes(like string, int, double..) for Oracle database and in its OJDBC?

Possible duplicate is this :

> [setObject() method of PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793483/setobject-method-of-preparedstatement)

But I want to know about using it for Oracle database and OJDBC.
What are possible problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible problems are:

1. You are delaying type validation till the application execution and don't take advantage of type safety. So you'll have errors during execution which could be easily caught at compilation time.
2. You are loosing control of how types are inferred which might
   lead to weird formatting in some cases

My advise is to use setObject only if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One problem that I came across is the ambiguity that arises in case of `null` values. In my application, this led to problems for the database to cache queries properly. To avoid this I had to check if the value was `null` and use [`#setNull(index, class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) in these cases.

For non-`null` values I haven't come across any problems.